# Only mouse is responsive after closing laptop lid

Tags: 11.04, unity, laptop, intel-graphics, freeze

I just upgraded to 11.04 and have been having this issue. I'm using the Unity interface, my card is an Intel GM965.

When I close my laptop lid I have it set to just blank screen. When I open the lid again, the mouse moves but nothing is responsive. I can switch to a terminal but when I switch back, the terminal text remains there with just the mouse moving again. I have to do a gdm restart to get Unity back.

Comment: same here, but that was present event in older versions and - for me, touchpad or keyboard can stop working at any time..

Comment: Having the same issue on an inspiron 15n, using classic mode. Then again, I'm also getting random disk swapping. :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the relevant bug report:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/728101

Answer (score 1):

Some possible fixes:

- Setting "OpenGL > Sync to VBlank [off]" in compiz settings manager (if you don't have it, sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager)
- killing gnome-power-manager (or remove it from start-up apps)
- Setting a screensaver

In my case though, none of those had any effect. I am still affected with the problem, but hopefully, since those worked for other users, they might work for you

ps: I know the question is old, but it appears in the first results of google when looking for the problem so I figured it should be answered

Comment: A workaround that does the trick for me: Before closing the lid, I open a new session (ctrl-alt-f2). Your session can be resumed with ctrl-alt-f7 or f8 (depends) when you open the lid. Works flawlessly here.